# Searching facebook graph api by date range not working....why?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

When I perform the following form query on Facebook Graph API Explorer, the date range seems to be being ignored.  No matter what range I used it brings back the same results.

Can date range searches only be used on specific kinds of queries, or is my query wrong?

https://graph.facebook.com/[formID]type=form&from_date=1552694400&to_date=1552780799&fields=id,leads%7Bform_id,ad_name,platform,created_time,field_data,custom_disclaimer_responses,retailer_item_id%7D

Unfortunately, I can't post a sample result due to GDPR.

Comment: timebased paging is usually done with `since` and `until`, are you sure `from_date` and `to_date` are valid parameters?

Comment: @luschn According to this page - if you scroll down to Filtering - it is.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving

Comment: @luschn Just tried `since` and `until`.  That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The doc you refer the parameters is related to the `export_csv` download url.

You should use:

> **Filtering Leads**
>
> This example filters leads based on timestamps. Timestamps should be
>   Unix timestamp.
>
> ```
> curl -X GET \
>   -d 'filtering=[
>        {
>          "field": "time_created",
>          "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
>          "value": 1552051944
>        }
>      ]' \
>   -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{adgroup-id}/leads
> ```

Optionally this other methods should work:

```
curl -X GET \
-d 'since=1454600660' \
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{adgroup-id}/leads
```

Hope this help

NB: you can use form-id instead of the adgroup-id

Comment: I'm using c# .net, but someone decided to remove those tags.

Also, that method requires you to download a file - I believe.  Not what I want to do.